# How to Pass a value via href - PHP

Tags: php, href

Am passing a value using href tag

In first page Href tag used as

```
echo "<a href=view_exp.php?compna=",$compname,">$compname</a>";
```

In the Second page used

```
$compname = $_GET['compna'];
```

To receive the Compna values are pass but only the first word is passed remaining words are skipped.

Compname as " Chiti Technologies Ltd "
When I pass the value I receive onlt "Chiti"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're only getting the first word of the company name is that the company name contains blanks. You need to encode the name.

```
echo "<a href=view_exp.php?compna=",urlencode($compname),">$compname</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You are producing ambiguous/invalid HTML by not quoting the parameter. The result is something like:

```
<a href=foo bar baz>
```

Only `foo` is recognized to belong to `href`, the rest doesn't. Quote the values:

```
echo '<a href="view_exp.php?compna=', urlencode($compname), '">', htmlspecialchars($compname), '</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
echo '<a href="view_exp.php?compna='.urlencode($compname).'">'.$compname.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need add quotes for your `href`, besides, you also need to use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode the variable.

```
echo '<a href="view_exp.php?compna=' . urlencode($compname) . '">' . $compname . '</a>';
```

Comment: `. '">$compname</a>"`?? The last `"` should be a `'` instead.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff Yep, fixed.

Comment: Ha... I already edited it, but it was 'in queue until it was peer reviewed`.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff Yep, but your edit let `$compname` in the single quotes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

change echo `"<a href=view_exp.php?compna=",$compname,">$compname</a>";`

to echo `"<a href=\"view_exp.php?compna=$compname\">$compname</a>";`

When using double quoted strings " you don't need to paste variables in between, you can just type them.
Also, when pasting strings together don't use comma's , but use . to paste strings otherwise you'll get parse errors.
For arrays include them between curly brackets {}

```
echo "<a href=\"view_exp.php?compna={$compname["whatever"]}\">$compname</a>";
```